# making my code right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

can some one tell me if there's something wrong in my code ?

i am using bootsrap is js and css files and in this code below it should open a dialog box but i don't know why it's not working. wanted to make sure if it's all ok here

```
<div class="modal fade details-1" id="details-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Levis Jeans</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="center-block">
                            <img src="images/products/men4.png" alt="Levis Jeans" class="details img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included the related javascript to your page?

Comment: so, please, show it.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2Riw5CfXshlWDuzaVbmT?p=preview here is whole the codes on my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a wrapper.

```
<div class="modal fade details-1" id="details-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Levis Jeans</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="center-block">
                                <img src="images/products/men4.png" alt="Levis Jeans" class="details img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-1"> Open</div>
```

Add `div.modal-content` under `.modal-dialog`.

Comment: how is that dear? can you edit the code and make it right ?

Comment: I already did. See it working here : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/45oV2

Comment: it worked after you added div.modal-content under .modal-dialog ?

Comment: Just Checked your code snippet. Your data-target is also misspelled as `data-target="#deatails-1"`

I have updated my bootsnipp with your html and the 2 fixes. You can see it working there now.

Comment: you have saved me :D how i didn't notice that . thanks a lot Elysium and all other users been helping me here

Comment: now it worked perfectly. thank you again. the mistake was on data-target="#deatails-1"

Comment: i have changed it from #deatails-1 to #details-1

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add class `<div class="modal-content">` and here is the working modal

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row text-center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-1">Click to open Modal</a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade details-1" id="details-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Levis Jeans</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="center-block">
                                <img src="images/products/men4.png" alt="Levis Jeans" class="details img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried your code but didn't work dear

Comment: Check now I added working example :)

Comment: thanks a lot dear and for all of your helps. but another user did it for me. thanks again dear